Conditional distribution involving deterministic transformation of a random variable
Consider a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $P(X)$ is known and a deterministic non-invertible transform $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $m < n$ and $Z = T(X)$.
What I want is the conditional distribution $p(X | Z)$. I was thinking to start with what must be true by the definition of $Z$,
$$p(Z | X) = \delta(Z - T(X))$$
which is simply a statement that $Z$ must be equal to $T(X)$ given $X$. I was then thinking to invert this via Baye's rule,
$$ p(X | Z) = \frac{p(Z | X) p (X)} {\int p(Z | X) p (X) dX} = \frac{\delta(Z - T(X)) p (X)} {\int \delta(Z - T(X)) p (X) dX}$$
However, it's not clear to me exactly how to work with "$\delta(Z - T(X))$" inside the integral, and whether this approach is actually valid or not (i.e. whether Baye's rule can be applied here). I am also troubled by how one would sample $p(X|Z)$ even if the denominator can be evaluated.
Would appreciate any guidance along these directions!

The integral over $\delta(z - T(X))$ is the measure of $T^{-1}({Z})$.
